# Meaning of しな in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> アタックのお手本と練習をすでに用意ずみなのダ！！
> 活用された**しな**のだ！

Here it follows a verb in past form, does that affect its meaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58258/9831 `... ～されたし, may be a little more popular (e.g., "ご注意されたし", "日程を調整されたし")`

Comment: Yes, that does, thank you for the clarification!